# How to disable tomcat server console log?

Tags: java, logging, struts2, log4j

My `log4j.proerties`

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,R
log4j.appender.R = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File = logs/backup.log
log4j.appender.R.Append = true
log4j.appender.R.DatePattern = '.'yyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.R.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %c{1} [%p] %m%n
log4j.additivity.info.release.scheduler=false
```

My `Action` class is

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LogAction.class);
if(getUname().equals("admin")&&getPwd().equals("123"))
{   
logger.info("Success");
return "su";
}
else
{
  addActionMessage("user name and password incorrectly!");
  logger.info("Failure");
  return "fa";
}
```

My `backup.log` file contain the following logs. These logs are coming from tomcat server

```
a2013-05-24 15:06:44 XmlConfigurationProvider [DEBUG] Loading action configurations 
from:   struts-default.xml
2013-05-24 15:06:44 XmlConfigurationProvider [DEBUG] Loaded action configuration
from:       struts-default.xml
2013-05-24 15:06:44 XmlConfigurationProvider [INFO] Parsing configuration file
[struts-default.xml]
2013-05-24 15:06:44 XmlConfigurationProvider [DEBUG] Loaded type: 
name:xwork   impl:com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory
2013-05-24 15:06:44 XmlConfigurationProvider [DEBUG] 
Loaded    type:com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory name:struts
```

but I want the following format only

```
2013-05-24 15:06:44 Login successfull.
2013-05-24 15:06:44 Login failure.
```

and my question is how to avoid unwanted logs write into the log file? And I am using Struts2 and log4j properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To turn off *unwanted* log using log4j configuration properties file via specifying the level for the logger based on the logger instantiated for the given class. For example

```
log4j.logger.org.apache=OFF,R
log4j.logger.com.opensymphony.xwork2=OFF,R
```

Comment: thanks for reply Roman. but still i have the following logs are repeated 2013-05-24 16:37:10 cache [DEBUG] Could not find template in cache, creating new one; id=[template/xhtml/form-close-validate.ftl[en_US,UTF-8,parsed] ] and another one is 2013-05-24 16:37:10 cache [DEBUG] Compiling FreeMarker template template/xhtml/form-close-validate.ftl[en_US,UTF-8,parsed]  how will i overcome this one

Comment: log is issued by some class and to prevent it you should configure it in the log4j configuration. Assumed log4j used by the struts framework. In the recent releases they made priority for sl4j logging mechanism. Anyway there's utility used by framework that produces the log and could be a pssibility to affect it like they did with `devMode`. Turning it off also removes much logs.

Comment: is it necessary to add anothet dependacy out of log4j to enable the rolling file appender?